# how to setup node with docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

i'm learning docker and nodejs, and i want to start a project with both of those tools.

What i'm trying to achieve is installing the node dependencies in the build phase of docker, and then copy the node_modules folder to my host machine via docker-compose volumes.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

COPY . /myproject/back/

WORKDIR /myproject/back/


RUN npm install --save-dev nodemon
RUN npm install --save \
  express \
  multer

CMD npm run dev
```

And this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"


services:

  back:
    build: ./back
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./back:/myproject/back
```

And when i run `docker-compose build` it builds correctly, but when i run `docker-compose up` i get this error:

```
back_1  | > back@1.0.0 dev
back_1  | > nodemon main.js
back_1  |
back_1  | sh: 1: nodemon: not found
back_1  | npm ERR! code 127
```

What am i missing? Is this the recommended approach?

Answer (score -1):

Nodemon should be used ideally only on your development environment. You can configure your dockercontainer to restart if an error occurs, discarding the need of Nodemon inside the container.

Now if you really want to have Nodemon running you node app inside docker, then you need to first install Nodemon globally:

Replace this `RUN npm install --save-dev nodemon` with this `RUN npm install -g nodemon`, this will make the command `nodemon` available in your container.